# How does the addbit bit manipulation function work in this permutation code sample

Tags: c, permutation

I have code to perform a permutation on a block of data (64 bit) and the code works but I don't understand how the addbit function works.  This is the function that performs the permutation on a to and from bit position.

I understand that because if a bit gets over-written in the destination data block then if that previous bit needs to be permuted then it will be lost and that is why there is a source and destination data block.

But I dont understand the logic in addbit.

Why is FIRSTBIT used?

The code works, but I would like to understand why.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// FIRSTBIT is first bit in 64 bit data?
#define FIRSTBIT 0x8000000000000000 // 1000000000...

// eg move bit 64 in input data to bit position 1
// then move bit 63 in input data to bit position 2 etc
const int TestPermutation[64] = {
    64, 63, 62, 61, 60, 59, 58, 57,
    56, 55, 54, 53, 52, 51, 50, 49,
    48, 47, 46, 45, 44, 43, 42, 41,
    40, 39, 38, 37, 36, 35, 34, 33,
    32, 31, 30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25,
    24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17,
    16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10,  9,
     8,  7,  6,  5,  4,  3,  2,  1
};

// move data bit from 'from' at position_from to position_to in block
// How does this work?  
void addbit(uint64_t *block, uint64_t from, int position_from, int position_to)
{
    if (((from << (position_from)) & FIRSTBIT) != 0)
        *block += (FIRSTBIT >> position_to);
}

// perform permutation based on TestPermutation array
void permute(uint64_t* data) {
    uint64_t data_temp = 0;
    for (int ii = 0; ii < 64; ii++)
    {
        addbit(&data_temp, *data, TestPermutation[ii] - 1, ii);
    }
    *data = data_temp;
}

void print_binary(uint64_t number) {
    for (int i = sizeof(uint64_t) * 8 - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        printf("%c", ((number >> i) & 1) ? '1' : '0');
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {

    uint64_t data = 0xF0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0;  // test block
    print_binary(data);  // 1111000011110000111100001111000011110000111100001111000011110000
    permute(&data);
    print_binary(data);  // 0000111100001111000011110000111100001111000011110000111100001111
}
```